# XML specified is not syntactically valid error while putting block blob list on azure storage using rest api

Tags: java, xml, rest, azure, storage

I'm trying to put block blob list to azure storage, but I'm getting "XML specified is not syntactically valid" error. I'm using REST API in java.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BlockList>
  <Latest>AA==</Latest>
  <Latest>AQ==</Latest>
  <Latest>Ag==</Latest>
  <Latest>Aw==</Latest>
  <Latest>BA==</Latest>
  <Latest>BQ==</Latest>
  <Latest>Bg==</Latest>
  <Latest>Bw==</Latest>
  <Latest>CA==</Latest>
  <Latest>CQ==</Latest>
  <Latest>Cg==</Latest>
  <Latest>Cw==</Latest>
  <Latest>DA==</Latest>
  <Latest>DQ==</Latest>
  <Latest>Dg==</Latest>
  <Latest>Dw==</Latest>
  <Latest>EA==</Latest>
  <Latest>EQ==</Latest>
  <Latest>Eg==</Latest>
  <Latest>Ew==</Latest>
  <Latest>FA==</Latest>
  <Latest>FQ==</Latest>
  <Latest>Fg==</Latest>
  <Latest>Fw==</Latest>
  <Latest>GA==</Latest>
  <Latest>GQ==</Latest>
  <Latest>Gg==</Latest>
</BlockList>
```

I'm sending it using `HttpRequest.put(url).send(...)`

Any ideas what could be a problem here?

Update: There are no errors when putting block list without any block:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BlockList>
</BlockList>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for converting the block ids into Base64 format string?

Comment: Have you tried sending it without the XML declaration?

Comment: @GauravMantri I can't right now. I'm using some standard java's library. You can see ids now and azure doesn't complain on ids while putting single block (using put block rest api)

Comment: Basically what I tried to do is try and convert it back into string using the following code (.Net) and got some corrput data: 


Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String("AA=="))


Can you check if you're creating block ids properly. Another thing you might want to check is that all block ids string are of same length.

Comment: @GauravMantri Base64String is strange: all libs are using different algorithms to convert it both ways, but Azure is accepting ids my code generated. And all ids are same length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem implementing straight against the REST API without a library. The default API version (unless you specify an alternate) doesn't support this xml schema for multipart uploads. Switching to `x-ms-version: 2011-08-18` fixed the problem for me.